# C char* to int conversion

Tags: c, char, int

How would I go about converting a two-digit number (type `char*`) to an `int`?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: Accept aam1r's answer if it was the solution please.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) can do that for you

Example:

```
char string[] = "1234";
int sum = atoi( string );
printf("Sum = %d\n", sum ); // Outputs: Sum = 1234
```

Answer (score 11):

Use atoi() from `<stdlib.h>`

http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi

Or, write your own `atoi()` function which will convert `char*` to `int`

```
int a2i(const char *s)
{
  int sign=1;
  if(*s == '-'){
    sign = -1;
    s++;
  }
  int num=0;
  while(*s){
    num=((*s)-'0')+num*10;
    s++;   
  }
  return num*sign;
}
```

Comment: a2i is perfect solution just need a fix for negative case add bracket on if will fix it

 if(*s == '-')
 {
  sign = -1;
  s++;
 }