# Converting char to int c++

Tags: c++, char, int

I'm loosing my mind at the moment and below is what I'm trying to do.

```
char* buffer;
sprintf(buffer, "0x%08x", 5);
*(int *)(0x834AF2AC + 0x1a) = ?buffer?;
```

Buffer = 0x05000000

I need to set that in memory, if I just set 05 it will set 0x00000005

Question asked better.
How can I convert an INT into a format of "0x%08x"
So 5 becomes 0x05000000

ANSWERD:
The correct answer is *(int *)(0x834AF2AC + 0x1a) = 5<<24;

Comment: You have bigger problems than converting to `int`. You are writing to some location you shouldn't be writing to. You need to initialize `buffer`.

Comment: So, `int x = 0x05000000;` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Why do you need the `0x` in your string?  Are you looking for a generic way to parse a string that represents an integer?  Do you want to consider octals, too?  What about longs?

Comment: xx and xxx shall be ignored in this question.

Comment: So, it still doesn't really make sense.  Do you have a string you need to parse or an int you're trying to make larger?

Comment: My question is very simple, I'd like to convert 5 into 0x05000000 as an integer. Why this is requested is unimportant, I cannot set it any other way. Yes I know it makes little sense.

Comment: So the string has absolutely nothing to do with it?  `int x = 5 << 24;`

Comment: Look: *(int *)(0x834AF2AC + 0x1a) = 0x05; < does not work *(int *)(0x834AF2AC + 0x1a) = 0x05000000; < does work but my values not static, its going to be dynamic from a param so I'll need to convert integers as "1", "2", "3" so on into the working format. Yes it sets memory but according to the game not how it wants it set.

Comment: Because you're putting it in the wrong address.  It would be much easier to get a good answer if you explained why you're doing this and didn't confuse the issue with the `int -> string -> int` nonsense.

Comment: What do you mean I'm putting it in the wrong address? I'm not understanding why you need to understand my app to answer how to convert 5 to 0x05000000

Comment: `0x5000000 == (5 << 24)`  Assuming your numbers are 255 or less then you're off by 3 bytes and should be using a char pointer rather than an int pointer.  Explaining why you want to do something completely avoids the entire xy problem you have here resulting in answers that are not helpful to you.

Comment: What is everyone talking about in my X problem? I'm so confused right now. That address is valid, very valid I can read / write to it.

Comment: Listen, I have no clue why 0x05 is not working over 0x05000000 but all I know is it works okay? I've tried to use a char pointer and it wont set the value now.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is *(int *)(0x834AF2AC + 0x1a) = 5<<24; :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cout, std::endl
#include <string>   // for std::string, std::stoi
int main()
{

  std::string s{"0x05"};
  int i = std::stoi(s, nullptr, 16); // convert base 16 number in s to int
  std::cout << i << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Not going to work, thanks anyway. I've updated my question again.

Comment: @user2887749 Your question makes no sense. An `int` is an `int`. `0x0005` is exactly the same as `5`.

Comment: I understand that, but according to the game I am writing memory to it is invalid and not okay to do so.

Comment: @user2887749 that could well be the fact that you have not allocated any memory for your buffer, as I mentioned in the very first comment.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having trouble understanding and thanks for your help man.

Comment: Look: *(int *)(0x834AF2AC + 0x1a) = 0x05; < does not work  *(int *)(0x834AF2AC + 0x1a) = 0x05000000; < does work 

but my values not static, its going to be dynamic from a param so I'll need to convert integers as "1", "2", "3" so on into the working format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly but if you want to convert an entire `string` to `int`, then I would suggest `stringstream`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

For hexadecimal string:

```
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream

int main () {

  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << std::hex << 0x05;

  int foo;
  ss >> foo;

  std::cout << "foo: " << foo << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two result from google which points to stackoverflow (result 1 and 2).

[Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)

[C char* to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145777/c-char-to-int-conversion)